# ActiveResource NameError in Overridden Devise class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeresource

I'm attempting to use an ActiveResource class (Staff) within an overridden Devise resource (User).  The purpose at this time is simply to return a list of Staff for the registering user to select from at registration time.

controllers/user/registrations_controller.rb

```
def new
   @list = Staff.find()
   super
end
```

models/staff.rb

```
require 'active_resource'

class Staff < ActiveResource::Base
   self.site = "http://localhost/Staff/"
end
```

My gem file includes **gem 'active_resource'**

When the overridden new method gets called the following error is displayed;

> NameError in User::RegistrationsController#new  uninitialized constant
>   User::RegistrationsController::Staff

Any ideas on how this can be overcome?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller you are referencing a `Staff` class, but in your model you define a `EposnowStaff` class. Try renaming `EposnowStaff` to `Staff`.

Comment: Having changed the Class name I get the reported error.  What confuses me is why the constant is reported as User::RegistrationsController::Staff?  Might this is the issue?

Comment: This error reporting is standard for how ruby reports missing constants in the context of another constant. You can experiment with this yourself by invoking an undefined constant: `module Monkey; Llama; end`. The issue is that ruby isn't finding the Staff constant, which should now be defined in `app/models/staff.rb` and autoloaded by rails. If you haven't already, try stopping your server, stop spring with `bin/spring stop` and try restarting your server and see if that gets the `Staff` constant to load correctly.